# How to synchronize iphone pictures to a linux laptop?

Tags: iphone, unix, file

Last year I purchased an iphone 8 which I connect through USB to my Linux laptop (Debian 12 bookworm). Now I need to change it because the screen is broken. Before doing that I would like to save the pictures to my laptop. icloud is not synchronizing because there are to many pictures. How can I synchronize pictures to the Linux laptop?

I can see the device connected in my file browser, but only a very small number of app related data directories appear (see screenshot)

[image]

Also

- I suppose the picture directory which should appear as DCIM according to some forums is protected? How to change the iphone restrictions so that pictures are visible from my laptop?
- Should I use one of the many file sharing apps?

  - Such as QRCP https://www.makeuseof.com/share-files-linux-android-ios-using-qrcp/
- Should I try to install Itunes on Linux using wine?
- The iphone's directory appears with an "afc://..." address in the file browser. Thanks to [a superuser Q&A](https://superuser.com/questions/1548122/how-can-i-access-afc-ios-files-from-the-ubuntu-terminal) I managed to open it and can see the app directories visible in the screenshot as such

  ```
    :/run/user/1000/gvfs/afc:host=.......,port=3$ ls
    AsheKube.CarnetsSci  com.agminstruments.drumpadmachine      org.videolan.vlc-ios
  ```

Comment: You say iCloud is not synchronizing, is icloud photos disabled on the phone? Review the steps here for Windows to see if it works for you https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201302

Comment: Thanks. No it's just that I have to 3000 pictures and didn't purchase the extension.

Comment: That's fine, I just wanted to make sure that it was disabled. If you don't have enough storage and don't intend to buy more storage, then you should turn off iCloud features that you can't use, to ensure no data loss.